# Launch Image Display Irregularities iOS5 / iOS6

Tags: ios

I am testing my launch images, I depend on the positioning and aspect ratios of my launch images to be correct and consistent, because I perform some animations after the launch image disappears. I am getting inconsistent positioning / aspect ratios for the launch image. See results here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/88UMW.jpg

First image is running on (iOS5), the second (iOS6).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

iOS5 shows the splash image SHRINKED to the space left below the status bar while
iOS6 shows the splash image OVERLAYED with the status bar.

Does your App show a status bar at all?
If it does not:
Verify you disabled it correctly in the .plist file and remove it from your splash image.
If it does:
Just remove it from the splash image. Your logo will be shrinked a bit on iOS5, but if you are lucky you can do your animation OS version dependenly to hide that issue.